# Pointer array and pointers in parantheses

Tags: c, pointers

Could anybody tell me what the difference is between

```
int *p[n];
```

and

```
int (*p)[n];
```

where `n` is any number?

I know that first case implies an array of pointers, but I would like to know what the second declaration implies.

Comment: Maybe [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) can help.

Answer (score 5):

- `int * p[10]` defines `p` as an array of ten `int`-pointers.
- `int (*p)[10]` defines `p` a pointer to an array of ten ints. So you could say:

  ```
  int a[10];

  int (*p)[10] = &a;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so C declarations are very confusing. This article seems to be a good guide to how to parse them. http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/How+To+Read+C+Declarations It seems the second case is a pointer to an array of size n.